# applying completableFuture inside a forEach loop java 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, apache-kafka, completable-future

i've a scheduled task in my spring boot application and i want to run it faster.

my task consist of fetching some data ( subscriptions ) and for each subscription, call an API client and send a message to my kafka broker.

this is my code

```java
    @Scheduled(cron="0 0 12 1/1 * ? *",zone = "Europe/Paris")
    public void execute() {

        List<StoreSubscription> storeSubscriptions = subscriptionRepository.findAllByExpirationDate(LocalDate.now().plusMonths(1));

        storeSubscriptions.forEach(subscription -> {
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> this.message(subscription))
                    .thenApply(message -> kt.send(SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED_REMINDER_EARLY,message));
        });
    }
```

are the messages created asynchronously? is a message created without waiting for the end of the previous message?

Thanks.

Comment: You could add a log statement in here to debug your assumptions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second message is not going to wait for the end of the first one.
That happens because the `CompletableFuture`s are not composed.

If you want them to be executed one after the other, you need something like this:

```
CompletableStage loop = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
storeSubscriptions.forEach(subscription -> {
    loop = loop.thenCompose( unusued -> CompletableFuture
                           .supplyAsync( () -> this.message(subscription))
                           .thenAccept(message -> kt.send(SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED_REMINDER_EARLY,message));
});
```

The drawback of this solution is that it might create many objects in memory.
To avoid this issue you could use the [IBM async utils](https://github.com/IBM/java-async-util):

```
Iterator iterator = storeSubscriptions.iterator();
AsyncTrampoline.asyncWhile( () -> CompletableFuture
                           .supplyAsync( () -> this.message(iterator.next()))
                           .thenAccept(message -> kt.send(SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRED_REMINDER_EARLY,message))
                           .thenApply( r -> iterator.hasNext() )
)
```

With Maven, you can add it to your project with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.async</groupId>
    <artifactId>asyncutil</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This library implements the [Trampoline pattern](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/trampoline/)